# Lentidão no primeiro acesso ao site recém hospedado

Tags: jsf, tomcat, hospedagem

boa tarde!

Estou começando a praticar meus estudos com desenvolvimento Web e ao hospedar e subir um site em JSF com Spring e Hibernate, o primeiro acesso é bem lento.
Depois que acessa, a manipulação é bem rápida.

Essa demora também acontece depois de algum tempo passado e um novo acesso for efetuado.

Estou achando que pode ser algum problema de configuração do Tomcat na hospedagem ou algum parâmetro que me falta configurar no ambiente.

Alguma dica, por favor?

1. Context.xml

   ```
   <Resource name="jdbc/baseDB" 
       auth="Container" 
       type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
       maxTotal="100" 
       maxIdle="30" 
       maxWaitMillis="10000"  
       validationQuery="SELECT 1" 
       validationInterval="30000" 
       username="root"
       password="root"
       driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base?autoReconnect=true" />
   ```

Avaliando o log do Tomcat acho que o problema está sendo a parada automática do Container:

```
INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer- A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
```

Depois de uns 20 minutos sem acessar o site, cai a mensagem acima no Log.
Daí o próximo acesso é lento novamente.

Answer (score 1):

No Primeiro acesso seu site deve estar iniciando o Hibernate, quando hibernate é iniciado ele verifica o persistence.xml, verifica a conexão com o banco , verifica as tabelas etc, por isso no primeiro acesso ele está lento.